# Dynamic query in procedure, how do I get OUT value?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, dynamic, return-value

I want to call a dynamic procedure with a particular time_stamp and `pro_id`.

In the first step I want to find out if that particular `pro_id` exists in the table. Is there anything wrong in the `Concat` statement? I do not get the desired `OUT` value

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE 'ADDCONSENSUS'(IN time_stamp int(10), IN pro_id INT(10), OUT cnt INT(11))
BEGIN
    SET @sql1 = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(pid) INTO @cnt  FROM ',time_stamp,' WHERE pid = ,pro_id);
    PREPARE stmt from @sql1;
    EXECUTE stmt;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `ADDCONSENSUS`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `ADDCONSENSUS`(
    IN `time_stamp` INT,
    IN `pro_id` INT,
    OUT `cnt` INT)
BEGIN
    SET @sql1 := CONCAT('
        SELECT COUNT(`pid`) INTO @`cnt`
        FROM `', CAST(`time_stamp` AS CHAR), '`
        WHERE `pid` = ', CAST(`pro_id` AS CHAR));
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql1;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    SET `cnt` := @`cnt`;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$

DELIMITER ;

CALL `ADDCONSENSUS`(1395395302, 3, @`_count`);
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/163ad/1)</kbd>